# AES-256 decryption with part of a key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

This is homework. Our professor encrypted a message with AES-256 in CBC mode (key is 256bits). Then he gave us the IV he used (`randomized` in my code), the encrypted message and second half of a key (`keySuffix`), key is in hexadecimal, IV too. We have to use brute-force and decrypt that message. The message is a few blocks of length 8 made of ones and zeroes with spaces in between (`cryptogram`). What I do is getting rid of the spaces, transforming cryptogram to `byteArray` (you can see in code how I do that). On the key I just do `getBytes()`, on IV I use `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary()` otherwise it's throwing an error about wrong IV length. When I get a message i return it as a String by using `new String(myByteArray)`. Then I check if that message has all the normal characters (not some 'bushes').

Point is that I get no results. I have no idea what may be wrong here, my guess is that some conversions are done not the way they were supposed to be. I've been trying some things with unicodes etc., but brute-force takes so long time to complete and testing like this is troublesome. Can someone point my in the right direction, like how to make those conversions. Generating all possible Strings for the other side of the key works fine.

btw. PKCS5Padding is giving an error.

```java
public class Main {
    private String randomized = "21232d0960a7b522d3e25141e54ecee6";
    private String keySuffix = "1dad418a";
    private String cryptogram = "00110001 01111000 01111101 01111100 01100001 11011110 10010010 01011011";
    private byte[] cryptogramBytes;
    private String pattern = "[a-zA-Z1-9\\s]*";
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec = null;
    private Cipher cipher = null;

    public static void main(String... args){
        char[] elements = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };
        char[] buff = new char[8];
        Main main = new Main ();
        byte[] convertedRandomized = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(main.randomized);
        main.ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(convertedRandomized);
        main.cryptogram = main.cryptogram.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        BigInteger bigint = new BigInteger(main.cryptogram, 2);
        main.cryptogramBytes = bigint.toByteArray();
        main.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        main.permGen(elements, 0, 8, buff);
    }

    public void permGen(char[] s, int i, int k, char[] buff){
        if (i < k) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
                buff[i] = s[j];
                permGen(s, i + 1, k, buff);
            }
        } else {
            String result = decrypt(String.valueOf(buff) + keySuffix);
            if (result.matches(pattern))
                System.out.println("Key is: " + String.valueOf(buff) + keySuffix);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String key){
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cryptogramBytes));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this exercise with inputs that you create yourself, i.e. with a known key and with a reduced search space (for example, with a small set of keys to test against, instead of trying full brute-force). Only after you are sure that the procedure is correct should you start the brute-force on the original exercise.

Comment: Note the `keySuffix` is only 32-bits of a 256-bit key, 1/8 of the key, not 1/2. It is not clear what the `cryptogram` is since it is a series of 1 & 0 in blocks of 8. None of this make sense for AES. Brute forcing 224-bits of an AES key is not possible. `pattern` seems to be missing `0`.There is something missing such as what the instructor was lecturing about in reguard to the problem.

Comment: I fully agree with zaph here. I suspect that the key bytes could be encoded with ASCII and that it makes up 1/2 of the key space. But even then, the cryptogram should be at least 16 bytes. Currently it seems to exist of 8 bytes in base 2 encoding (which you can actually parse using `(byte) Integer.parseInt(String, 2)` individually). Are you sure you're displaying all information you've got?